# Adding an object to an array in a sub-document in mongoose, mongodb. Property 'messages` could not be found

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have four models: `teacher`, `student`, `teacherMessageSchema`,`studentMessageSchema`. `teacherMessageSchema` is a subdocument in the 'teacher `model in the` messages: [teacherMessageSchema]  `property, and` studentMessageSchema`is a subdocument in the`student `model in the` messages: [studentMessageSchema] `property. How to add an object to arrays`[teacherMessageSchema]`and`[studentMessageSchema]`. I tried to do this like this:

```
module.exports.sendMessage = (req, res) => {
    
    let {sender, receiver, msg} = req.body;
    var hex = /[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}/g;

    sender = (hex.test(sender))? mongoose.Types.ObjectId(sender) : sender;
    receiver = (hex.test(receiver))? mongoose.Types.ObjectId(receiver) : receiver;

    Teacher.findById({_id: receiver}, function(err, member) {
        console.log(member, 'member');

        member.messages.push({msg});

        console.log('messages', member.messages)
        
        member.save(function(err, updated) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
    
            res.json(updated, 'updated');
        });
    });
}
```

But the property `messages` cannot be found.

**teacher and student model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const crypto = require('crypto');
const {studentMessageSchema, teacherMessageSchema} = require('./message');


const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        maxLength: 32
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true
    }
}, {timestamps: true});


const studentSchema = userSchema.clone();
studentSchema.add({
    messages : [studentMessageSchema]
});

const teacherSchema = userSchema.clone();
teacherSchema.add({
    messages : [teacherMessageSchema]
});



const User =  mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
const Student = mongoose.model('Student', studentSchema);
const Teacher = mongoose.model('Teacher', teacherSchema);

module.exports = {
    User,
    Student,
    Teacher
}
```

**message model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const messageSchema = new Schema({
    "contentInfo" : {
        "viewed" : {type: Boolean, default: false},
        "msg" : {type: String, required: true},
        "createdAt" : { type : Date, default: Date.now }
    }
});

const studentMessageSchema = messageSchema.clone();
studentMessageSchema.add({
    "receiver" : {
        type: Schema.ObjectId
    }
});

const teacherMessageSchema = messageSchema.clone();
teacherMessageSchema.add({
    "sender" : {
        type: Schema.ObjectId
    }
});


module.exports = {
    messageSchema,
    teacherMessageSchema,
    studentMessageSchema
}
```

**controller message**

```
const User = require('../models/user');
const Student = require('../models/user');
const Teacher = require('../models/user');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports.sendMessage = (req, res) => {
    
    let {sender, receiver, msg} = req.body;
    var hex = /[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}/g;

    sender = (hex.test(sender))? mongoose.Types.ObjectId(sender) : sender;
    receiver = (hex.test(receiver))? mongoose.Types.ObjectId(receiver) : receiver;

    Teacher.findById({_id: receiver}, function(err, member) {
        console.log(member, 'member');

        member.messages.push({msg});

        console.log('messages', member.messages)
        
        member.save(function(err, updated) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
    
            res.json(updated, 'updated');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: when you insert students and teachers in db, do you set a messages:[] filed for Schema?

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi yes. For example when student is register I see in database mongodb that property messages is added. And IT is array

Comment: is `msg` a model of messageSchema? or is it a String?

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi In message schema I had defined two schema. I removed one, Can you look now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before push `msg` you must to create message model, after that push it to `user.messages`

```
let {studentMessageSchema}= require("path of messeages Schema/")


module.exports.sendMessage = (req, res) => {
    
    let {sender, receiver, msg} = req.body;
    var hex = /[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}/g;
    sender = (hex.test(sender))? mongoose.Types.ObjectId(sender) : sender;
    receiver = (hex.test(receiver))? mongoose.Types.ObjectId(receiver) : receiver;

     //create a studentMessage Model
    let studentMessage =  new studentMessageSchema({
      contentInfo : {
          msg : msg
       },
      receiver : receiver
     })


    Teacher.findById({_id: receiver}, function(err, member) {
        console.log(member, 'member');

        member.messages.push({studentMessage });

        console.log('messages', member.messages)
        
        member.save(function(err, updated) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
    
            res.json(updated, 'updated');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I have model message. Look at my code 'messageSchema"

Comment: for example, in student schema you defined  `messages : [studentMessageSchema]` so you can just push `stunedentMessage model` in messages field, but you want a `{msg}` push it(that `msg` just a string), before push `msg` create a model, I updated my answer

Comment: I have error: `MongooseError [ObjectParameterError]: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got`

Comment: Send me github link of project to chech it

Comment: I send a message to the user via the form on his profile. How to search for users to whom I have already sent a message via the form on their profile. My point is how to find users that I have already sent a message to and display these people in a chat list. I have two models 'student' and 'teacher'. Find all id from 'receiver' property in 'student' collection? Write them on the board? Using these indexes from the array, search for objects in the 'teachers' collection?

Comment: Exactly, Find all id from 'receiver'(in array messages ) property in 'student' collection, after get all Id's teacher, based on ID's teacher you can get extra data from teache

Comment: if you have one model for messages, and the mode had a receiver and sender, you can search in messages Model, but in this approach it's not possible

Comment: thanks. I have two modela messages for student (with property receiver) and second model message for tutor (with property sender)